# How to format difference between 2 moment date

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, next.js

There is start date and end date. Using moment ,will get difference between 2 dates in hours.

```
  var now = moment(sessionData.StartTime); 
  var end = moment(sessionData.EndTime); 
  var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(now));
  var days = duration.asHours();
  it returns : 3.08 .
```

I want to show that difference like this- 3 hrs 15 m.
Is this possible to achieve

Comment: you want to round it  up?

Comment: 3.08 is the difference.I want to show it as 3 hrs 15 m

Answer (score 0):

Try get the difference between two days using `diff` followed by expressing it terms of `duration`. Then you would be able to get exact number of days, hours, minutes

```
let now = moment("2017-01-26T14:21:22+0000");
let expiration = moment("2017-01-29T17:24:22+0000");
let diff = expiration.diff(now);
let diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);

let dayDiff = diffDuration.days() + "d";
let hoursDiff = diffDuration.hours() + "hrs";
let minDiff = diffDuration.minutes() + "m";
console.log(`${dayDiff} ${hoursDiff} ${minDiff}`);
```